# â€œ character are shown in the csv

Tags: perl, csv, utf-8

I am parsing a site and writing the content in a csv file using Perl where I see `â€ ,â€œ` junk values in the content on the csv.

```
use utf8;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1, eol => "\n" } )  # should set binary attribute.
or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();                      
open my $fh, ">>:encoding(utf8)", "Test.csv" or die "Test.csv: $!";     
$csv->print($fh, [$title,$content]);  
$csv->eol();
```

the site is encoded with utf8.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Update :

@ikegami : Thanks ,the output of your code  gives the same character as

```
\x{201c}HexTab\x{201d}
```

Update 2:
Thanks 
if i use `">>:encoding(cp1252)"` it solves the quotes characters issue, but it throws some warning,

```
"\x{03bc}" does not map to cp1252 at c:/Perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 417
"\x{ff1c}" does not map to cp1252 at c:/Perl/lib/IO/Handle.pm line 417
```

Comment: You probably forgot to decode your inputs. What's the output of `use Data::Dumper; local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($title,$content));`

Comment: Do you see the `â€œ` characters in a UTF-8 capable display (editor or shell)? Then you're double encoding your data. Try dropping the `:encoding(utf8)` output layer.

Comment: @nwellnhof, It's better to decode all your inputs rather than dealing with both decoded and encoded strings. I disagree with your solution.

Comment: @ikegami: I suspect that Text::CSV already encodes UTF-8 strings and using a IO layer encodes the output twice.

Comment: @nwellnhof, It doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it you expect to see the following:

```
“HexTab”
```

And you see the following instead:

```
â€œHexTabâ€�
```

You're saving the file as UTF-8, but the program reading the file is decoding it using cp1252. These two have to match!

Two options:

1. Encode the text using cp1252 (`:encoding(cp1252)`) if the reader is going to continue decoding it using cp1252.
2. Have the reader decode the file using UTF-8 if you're going to encode it as UTF-8 (`:encoding(UTF-8)`).

Generally speaking, the latter is the better option as it allows the file to contain any Unicode character rather than an abysmally small subset.

Answer (score 1):

There a program called [iconv](http://man.cx/iconv) on most Unix systems that can re-encode files from one encoding to another. You need to determine the original encoding of your file.

You would run iconv as:

```
$ iconv -f utf8 -t cp1252 $file_name.csv > $new_file_name.csv
```

This would translate a file written in Windows using the default Code Page 1252 and convert it into UTF-8 encoding. I would first try `cp1252` and see if that works. If not, try `cp1250`, `latin1`, and `macintosh` (It could have been a file created with [MacRoman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman).

See if `iconv` can get rid of the issue.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I misunderstood the direction. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Why wouldn't he just use :encoding(cp1252) instead of using :encoding(UTF-8) + iconv?

Comment: He could. I thought his problem was that he was reading a CVS file with a Perl program, and that CVS file had the wrong encoding.

Comment: He's creating the CVS from web pages in Perl. He didn't specify what's reading it. If it was a Perl script, it would simply be a case of changing one `:encoding()` for another in that case too.